# How to use django-multiselect field in postman?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, postman, django-multiselectfield

I am using pip module MultiSelectField
Here is my model

```
SALES_CHANNEL = [
    ('retailer', 'Retailer'),
    ('wholesaler', 'Wholesaler'),
    ('consumer', 'Consumer'),
    ('distributor', 'Distributor'),
    ('online', 'Online')
]

class ProductModel(basemodel.BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mrp = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    dimensions = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, default='goods'
    )
    sales_channel = MultiSelectField(
        choices=SALES_CHANNEL, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

While creating a product with postman, my request body is:

```
{
    "name": "first unit",
    "sku": "first sales chann",
    "sales_channel":["retailer", "wholesaler"]

}
```

But on serializer.is_valid(), I get this error:

```
        "sales_channel": [
            "\"['retailer', 'wholesaler']\" is not a valid choice."
        ],
```

How can I post data on postman for multiselectfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post sales_channel multiple times in form data like:

sales_channel: retailer
sales_cahnnel: wholesaler

N.B: Not in raw data.
Ok fine, let me help you. Could you add the below details to your serializer before your meta data ex:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
sales_channel = serializers.ListField()
     class Meta:
         model = YourModel
```

Comment: But how can I achieve this in raw_data? I am sending all of my data as raw_data only, cant chnage that

Answer (score 1):

Small Update to the currently accepted answer by @skhynixsk
I found it better to use `MultipleChoiceField()` instead of `ListField()` since we can pass the correct choices inside `MultipleChoiceField()` for validation. If we use just `ListField()`, it will accept anything as the correct choice, instead of validating the required correct choices.

`sales_channel = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(["retailer", "wholesaler"])`

More on `MultipleChoiceField()` [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#multiplechoicefield)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you need to change your serializer

```
from rest_framework import fields    

class CustomMultipleChoiceField(fields.MultipleChoiceField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return list(super().to_representation(value))

class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sales_channel = CustomMultipleChoiceField(choices=SALES_CHANNEL, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        fields = '__all__'
```